# python plotting eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, pca, eigenvector, orthogonal

I thought that eigenvectors had to be orthogonal to each other. The following seems to violate that. I wanted to check if I am doing something wrong. Thank you for any insight!!!

Here is the code for the PCA (data at bottom of post)

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import cov
from numpy.linalg import eig


#calculate the mean of each column
M = mean(df.T, axis=1)

# center columns by subtracting column means
C = df - M

# calculate covariance matrix of centered matrix
V = cov(df.T)

# eigendecomposition of covariance matrix
values, vectors = eig(V)

# project data
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T)

#Make a list of (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(values[i]), vectors[:,i]) for i in range(len(values))]

# Sort the (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples from high to low
eig_pairs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)


matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(20,1), eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(20,1)))
#print('Matrix W:\n', matrix_w)
```

All I did here to plot the eigenvectors was grab the first two rows of matrix_w.  Is this correct? I just manually typed them into array M. Is my matrix_w wrong or is this incorrect vector selection for the first two principal components?

````
M =  np.array([[0.00747255,  0.16222854],[-0.18394907,  0.12426324]])
rows,cols = M.T.shape

#Get absolute maxes for axis ranges to center origin
maxes = 1.1*np.amax(abs(M), axis = 0)

for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
    xs = [0,M[i,0]]
    ys = [0,M[i,1]]
    plt.plot(xs,ys)

plt.plot(0,0,'ok') #<-- plot a black point at the origin
plt.axis('equal')  #<-- set the axes to the same scale

plt.legend(['V'+str(i+1) for i in range(cols)]) #<-- give a legend
plt.grid(b=True, which='major') #<-- plot grid lines
plt.show()```
````

Here is what the plotted vectors look like  but they are not orthogonal.

[image]

Here's the data (already np.log normalized):

```
[[1.954242509439325,
  1.6901960800285136,
  1.9444826721501687,
  1.2787536009528289,
  1.7558748556724915,
  1.7075701760979363,
  1.2787536009528289,
  1.3222192947339193,
  1.4313637641589874,
  1.3222192947339193,
  1.9084850188786497,
  1.8750612633917,
  1.6434526764861874,
  1.8512583487190752,
  1.3424226808222062,
  1.9590413923210936,
  1.9294189257142926,
  1.8692317197309762,
  1.4771212547196624,
  1.414973347970818],
 [1.9138138523837167,
  1.0,
  1.7781512503836436,
  0.3010299956639812,
  1.7403626894942439,
  1.6127838567197355,
  0.47712125471966244,
  0.3010299956639812,
  0.6020599913279624,
  0.3010299956639812,
  1.8260748027008264,
  1.8512583487190752,
  0.9542425094393249,
  1.662757831681574,
  1.9030899869919435,
  1.8195439355418688,
  1.380211241711606,
  1.9731278535996986,
  0.6989700043360189,
  1.255272505103306],
 [1.9444826721501687,
  1.6232492903979006,
  1.7993405494535817,
  0.6020599913279624,
  1.8808135922807914,
  1.724275869600789,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.3617278360175928,
  1.0413926851582251,
  0.6989700043360189,
  1.9395192526186185,
  1.9242792860618816,
  1.6020599913279623,
  1.6532125137753437,
  1.9444826721501687,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.6720978579357175,
  1.5563025007672873,
  1.7558748556724915,
  0.47712125471966244],
 [1.9822712330395684,
  1.792391689498254,
  1.9912260756924949,
  1.505149978319906,
  1.792391689498254,
  1.8260748027008264,
  1.6334684555795864,
  0.8450980400142568,
  1.146128035678238,
  1.146128035678238,
  1.919078092376074,
  1.9493900066449128,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.9084850188786497,
  1.1760912590556813,
  1.4913616938342726,
  1.9867717342662448,
  1.1139433523068367,
  1.724275869600789,
  1.1760912590556813],
 [1.9731278535996986,
  1.5797835966168101,
  1.6812412373755872,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.8692317197309762,
  1.568201724066995,
  1.3617278360175928,
  0.9542425094393249,
  1.1139433523068367,
  1.0791812460476249,
  1.8808135922807914,
  1.8808135922807914,
  1.6232492903979006,
  1.7558748556724915,
  1.462397997898956,
  1.9242792860618816,
  1.9030899869919435,
  1.919078092376074,
  1.3010299956639813,
  0.6989700043360189],
 [1.9867717342662448,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.9344984512435677,
  1.4471580313422192,
  1.8976270912904414,
  1.863322860120456,
  1.0791812460476249,
  0.8450980400142568,
  1.414973347970818,
  1.3617278360175928,
  1.9294189257142926,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.919078092376074,
  1.3010299956639813,
  1.9590413923210936,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.9242792860618816,
  1.4913616938342726,
  1.380211241711606],
 [1.4313637641589874,
  1.9344984512435677,
  1.99563519459755,
  1.3424226808222062,
  1.9590413923210936,
  1.7403626894942439,
  1.8808135922807914,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.3010299956639813,
  1.380211241711606,
  1.8808135922807914,
  1.8325089127062364,
  1.9493900066449128,
  1.9590413923210936,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.9777236052888478,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.7558748556724915,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.4471580313422192],
 [1.8573324964312685,
  1.414973347970818,
  1.8864907251724818,
  0.3010299956639812,
  1.3424226808222062,
  1.5314789170422551,
  0.0,
  0.6989700043360189,
  1.3010299956639813,
  0.47712125471966244,
  1.3424226808222062,
  1.7075701760979363,
  0.9030899869919435,
  1.2041199826559248,
  1.9493900066449128,
  1.8129133566428555,
  1.8920946026904804,
  1.9637878273455553,
  0.7781512503836436,
  0.9542425094393249],
 [1.7403626894942439,
  1.4913616938342726,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.1760912590556813,
  1.462397997898956,
  1.5185139398778875,
  0.0,
  0.6989700043360189,
  1.1760912590556813,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.6901960800285136,
  1.6232492903979006,
  1.146128035678238,
  1.6127838567197355,
  1.7075701760979363,
  1.7075701760979363,
  1.8573324964312685,
  1.4471580313422192,
  1.1139433523068367,
  1.0413926851582251],
 [1.863322860120456,
  1.8573324964312685,
  1.9294189257142926,
  1.3979400086720377,
  1.4913616938342726,
  1.8388490907372552,
  1.0,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.2787536009528289,
  1.1760912590556813,
  1.8976270912904414,
  1.845098040014257,
  1.662757831681574,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.806179973983887,
  1.9138138523837167,
  1.6812412373755872,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.6812412373755872,
  1.4771212547196624],
 [1.9822712330395684,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.9637878273455553,
  1.5440680443502757,
  1.8195439355418688,
  1.505149978319906,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.7075701760979363,
  1.6232492903979006,
  1.9084850188786497,
  1.8573324964312685,
  1.6989700043360187,
  1.806179973983887,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.9637878273455553,
  1.9590413923210936,
  1.4771212547196624,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.5314789170422551],
 [1.9637878273455553,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.919078092376074,
  1.1139433523068367,
  1.792391689498254,
  1.7075701760979363,
  0.6020599913279624,
  1.2304489213782739,
  1.4771212547196624,
  1.1760912590556813,
  1.7853298350107671,
  1.8573324964312685,
  1.5314789170422551,
  1.7075701760979363,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.7993405494535817,
  1.9731278535996986,
  1.4471580313422192,
  0.3010299956639812,
  1.792391689498254],
 [1.4771212547196624,
  1.7160033436347992,
  1.99563519459755,
  1.0413926851582251,
  1.9030899869919435,
  1.8750612633917,
  1.255272505103306,
  0.3010299956639812,
  0.6989700043360189,
  0.47712125471966244,
  1.7558748556724915,
  1.7160033436347992,
  1.662757831681574,
  1.9493900066449128,
  0.6989700043360189,
  1.9867717342662448,
  1.3979400086720377,
  1.4913616938342726,
  0.47712125471966244,
  0.9542425094393249]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Real coffee', 'Instant coffee', 'Tea', 'Sweetener', 'Biscuits',
       'Powder soup', 'Tin soup', 'Potatoes', 'Frozen fish', 'Frozen veggies',
       'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Tinned fruit', 'Jam', 'Garlic', 'Butter',
       'Margarine', 'Olive oil', 'Yoghurt', 'Crisp bread'])
```

Comment: There is no constraint on Eigenvectors that says they have to be orthogonal. The eigenvectors of a correlation matrix should be orthogonal. It's hard to follow your sorting, why don't you just check for orthogonallity of all pairs of `vectors` using `np.dot(vectors[:, col_i], vectors[:, col_j])`. If they're orthogonal this dot product should be 0 for all i and j (except i==j).

Comment: Consider sorting something like this instead: `order = np.argsort(values)`, `matrix_w = vectors[:, order]`

Comment: Also what was the shape of `vectors`? Unless it was 2-by-2, it looks like you've clipped the vectors so of course they are no longer orthognal, you just projected them down to 2D from (I assume) 20D

Comment: @Dan the shape of vectors is (20,20).  i'm not understanding how to check for orthogonality using np.dot - do i need to do a loop? could i do something like matrix_w.dot(matrix_w.T)

Comment: You could use a loop. Otherwise, I think maybe `vectors @ vectors.T` effectively does a pairwise dot product of each pair (just look the lower triangle). Your orthogonality is in 20D, when you project down to 2D, there is no reason for it to remain orthogonal. Think of what happens when you project 3D axes down to 2D (like on every 3D chart you've ever seen), the z-axis is no longer orthogonal to x or y. This is essentially what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple check for orthogonality of two vectors is to see if there dot product is zero. In your case, the orthogonal vectors should be the columns of `vectors` (i.e. the Eigenvectors of the covariance matrix). For example the following should run without raising the error

```
n, m = vectors.shape
for col_i in range(m):
    for col_j in range(m):
        if col_i < col_j:  # use strictly less than because we don't want to consider a column with itself, and the dot product is commutable so order doesn't matter
            is_orthogonal = np.dot(vectors[:, col_i], vectors[:, col_j])
            if not np.isclose(is_orthogonal, 0):
                raise ValueError(f"Eigenvector {col_i} and Eigenvector {col_j} are not orthogonal.")
```

A quicker way is to remember that a matrix product is just the dot product of the rows of the first matrix with the columns of the second i.e. `vectors.T @ vectors`. We then want to check that the lower triangle of this result excluding the diagonal (for the same reas as the `if col_i < col_j` in the loop) are all zero:

```
np.all(np.isclose(np.tril(vec.T @ vec, -1), 0))
```

This should return `True`

The reason that your plot doesn't look orthogonal is because you took two 20D vectors and arbitrarily projected them down to 2D. When you do this, there is no guarantee that they will remain orthogonal. As an example, consider the common xyz-axis diagram:

[image]

You know that the z axis is orthogonal to the x axis but if you project it down to 2D then the angle you see depends on the angle of projection and is no longer orthogonal.